# Unity, como mover um cubo de forma que ele ande sempre de 1 em 1

Tags: unity3d

Estou criando um joguinho de aprendizado em `Unity (C#)`,fiz este código para mover meu player de um em um quadrado

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// Esta classe é responsável por movimentar e interagir o objeto Player
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    // Variáveis compostas
    private Vector3 speed; // speed é um vetor 3, ele representa cada direção que o Player anda (x e z)

    // Variáveis primitivas
    private float timer; // timer é um cronômetro, ele representa o tempo de deslocação do player

    // Métodos de MonoBehaviour
    public void start(){ // Quando o objeto é criado
        speed = new Vector3(0,0,0); // speed é iniciado com zero (Player parado)
        timer = 0; // timer inicia zerado (Player pode se mover)
    }

    public void update(){ // Enquanto o objeto existir
        if(timer > 0){ // se timer for maior que zero (cronômetro iniciado)
            timer -= Time.deltaTime; // timer dimui conforme delta time (1/fps)
            transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime); // Player se move com base em speed veses delta time
        } else // senão
            move(); // Pode-se mover
    }

    // Métodos da classe
    public void move(){ // Move o player em x e z
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)){ // se existir entrada com tecla A
            speed.Set(-1,0,0); // modifica speed para -1 em x
            timer = 1; // inicia o timer
        } else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)){ // se existir entrada com tecla D
            speed.Set(1,0,0); // modifica speed para 1 em x
            timer = 1; // inicia o timer
        }
    }
}
```

Ele não vai para os lados quando eu pressiono as teclas... O que pode ser???

Comment: Para formatar seu código de múltiplas linhas, não use os ticks (apóstrofo invertido \`); selecione as linhas de código e aperte `ctrl+k`. Sobre sua questão, seu jogo é RTA? Ou é baseado em turnos? Vai ter animação ou o personagem vai simplesmente se teletransportador? (Sim, eu sei que o cubo é um _placeholder_ para o personagem, mas se modelar para o uso adequado se torna mais fácil por o objeto real)

Comment: É só um jogo de aprendizado. Estou começando com Unity. É um cubo, que se move de 1 em 1, que tem que arrastar objetos x para lugares x. Se todos os objetos estiverem na determinada posição... Ele passa de fase

Answer (score 1):

### O problema

As funções `Start` e `Update` estão em minúsculo. De acordo com a documentação do Unity, [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) e [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) são em maiúsculo.

As [convenções de nomenclatura](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) do C# podem ser úteis para você.

### Sugestão

Você pode usar [`GetAxisRaw`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html) no Unity ao invés de `GetKeyDown` nessa situação. Você colocar `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` como `x` e  `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` no `z` do vetor `speed` dentro do seu `Update()`. O código ficará mais legível e compacto.